# inject() must be called from injection context

Tags: angular

My project is on angular 13 and every component library i have installed dont work and the console reads inject() must be called from injection context.
Here is a usecase of the swipper.js module in my app:

```
//balance.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BalanceComponent } from './balance.component';
import { SwiperModule } from "swiper/angular";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [BalanceComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SwiperModule
  ],
  exports:[BalanceComponent]
})
export class BalanceModule { }
```

```
<swiper
[slidesPerView]="3"
[spaceBetween]="50"
(swiper)="onSwiper($event)"
(slideChange)="onSlideChange()"
>
```

```
//balance.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from 'src/app/common.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'balance-box',
  templateUrl: './balance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./balance.component.scss'],
})
export class BalanceComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user;
  constructor(
    public $common:CommonService
  ) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
   
  }

}
```

```
//common.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FlutterwaveService } from './flutterwave.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  constructor(
    public $http:HttpClient,
    public $api:ApiService,
    public $spinner:NgxSpinnerService,
    public $router:Router,
    public $flutterwave:FlutterwaveService,
    public $alert:AlertController
  ) { }
  public async user()
  {
   return this.$http.get(this.$api.base()+"/client",{headers:await this.$api.authHeaders()});
  }

}
```

And i get: inject() must be called from injection context.
Is this an angular 13 bug, if so how can i fix it?

Comment: can you show BalanceComponent ?

Comment: Added now @Random

Comment: what is CommonService ? Is it a service you made ? Can you show it (it should have the `providedIn: 'root'` config). Also, adding a `$` prefix is strange. What does it stand for ?

Comment: Added it now @Random, common service is the service used to transport a lot of services i will use on multiple components without importing each individually. And the $ prefix doesent stand for or mean much, ive just grown accustomed to using it in services

Comment: I don't see anything strange in what you wrote indeed. The only thing I don't know is Swiper. Is it an external lib ? If so, is it compatible with Angular 13 ?

Comment: Yes it is an external lib, it isnt just swiper that doesent work, a lot of external libraries provide the same error

Comment: When you upgrade angular, you have to check each of the lib you use to see if they also upgraded to angular 13. If a library did not upgrade to angular 13, you won't be able to use it.

Comment: Please how can i downgrade angular in the project? maybe to 11

Comment: cannot downgrade. you have to come back to the commit you did before upgrading your app to angular 13. If your app is small, you may generate a whole new project in the angular version you wish, and then copy paste your code into it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working
had to add

```
"paths": { "@angular/*": [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ] }
```

To the compiler options of my tsconfig.app.json. I still hate angular

Answer (score 0):

As I suggest in [inject() must be called from an injection context on angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181547/inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context-on-angular/77067868#77067868),

Try to use **@Inject** decorator:

```
import {
  ...
  Inject,
} from '@angular/core';

import { YourService } from '../../services/your-service.service';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ...
  constructor(@Inject(YourService) readonly yourService: YourService) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Also you can add **YourService** to your root **providers**, for example (if you have problems):

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    YourService,
  ],
  ...
})
```